Keycloak SAML SSO access Token using a java API
I was trying to implement Keycloak SAML SSO to my springboot project. I created a realm in keycloak "SP_Realm" and added a client "saml_sp" with protocol SAML. I want to create a handshake with the IDP and configure the security filter. Then I want an access token for this client. I have to do all this using java and I dont know how to do this. Please help me here.
Keycloak kc = KeycloakBuilder.builder()                 .serverUrl("http://localhost:8080/auth")                 .realm("master")                 .username("admin")                 .password("secret")                 .clientId("saml_sp")                 .clientSecret("")                 .resteasyClient(                         resteasyClientBuilder.connectionPoolSize(10).build()                 ).build();
But shows error HTTP 404 Not found
